# pgfplots: enlarge x limits while using x min/max

Tags: pgfplots

The problem: I like to use `enlarge x limits` to have some white space to the axes. I now often load in my data (generated elsewhere) but only want to plot a specific range (using `x min/max`). Now, doing so will not end up in white space since there is more data outside the plotted range. Is there an easy (built-in) way to 'cut-off' the plotted data at the position defined by `x min/max` and `enlarge x limits`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.85\linewidth,
height=5cm,
enlarge x limits=0.05,
enlarge y limits=0.05,
xmin = 2,
xmax = 6
]

\addplot[black] coordinates {
(1, 2)
(2, 2.5)
(3, 1.5)
(4, 1.4)
(5, 1.3)
(6, 1.1)
(7, 0.9)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To actually filter out the values that fall out of the desired range, use `restrict x to domain=<xmin>:<xmax>` instead of `xmin=<xmin>` and `xmax=<xmax>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.85\linewidth,
height=5cm,
enlarge x limits=0.05,
enlarge y limits=0.05,
restrict x to domain=2:6
]

\addplot[black] coordinates {
(1, 2)
(2, 2.5)
(3, 1.5)
(4, 1.4)
(5, 1.3)
(6, 1.1)
(7, 0.9)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Damn that was fast...